# angular redirection after submiting search form

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am working on a SpringBoot and Angular 5 web app, where I have a search form in the header:

```
<div class="searchDiv float-right">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onsubmit()" >
      <input class="searchBtn searchBtnHeader" type="text" role="search" placeholder="Search..." title="search field">
      <button class="fa fa-search align-middle searchBtn searchIcone" type="submit" [routerLink]="['/search']"></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I do redirection to a more detailed search page(component) in Angular 5?

Comment: Do it in the controller: in a submit handler for the form, do whatever you need to with the form and then [router.navigate()](https://angular.io/guide/router) to your destination

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `onSubmit()` method, you can add a programmatic redirection, like this

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

onSubmit() {
  // some stuff
  this.router.navigate(['/search']);
}
```

So you don't need anymore the `[routerLink]` attribute in your submit button.

For a complete guide on Angular 5 redirection ,take a look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/router) detailled tutorial

Comment: Hi, this will get moderated as a link-only answer: can you please take some of the information out of the tutorial and paste it inline (like the other answer has)?

Answer (score 7):

Programatically route from onsubmit() method

In Class

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
...
onsubmit() {
      this.router.navigate(['/search']);
}
```