# Angular request redirect to URL after POST submission

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-a-landing-page-with-mailchimp-and-angular-f2b636c5c7fa) to create a MailChimp submission form. I have replaced the list information & id and the tutorial with my own. On submission of the form, I want to redirect to a Thank You page, which was not shown in the tutorial.

When I submit user email to the list, I get a `200` response back from the server on my POST request.

However, I have two problems.

#1 The redirect does not navigate to the `'/thanks'` route. I'm not sure if this is the actual way this function should be used for navigation. I thought it would work similar to React's `this.history.push`. I got the basic idea for this function from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100797/angular-redirection-after-submiting-search-form)

**subscribe-form-component.ts**

```
export class SubscribeFormComponent implements OnInit {
  subscribeData: any = <any>{};
  constructor(
    private subscribeService: SubscribeService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {}



  onSuccess() {
    this.router.navigate(['/thanks']);
}


  subscribe(subscribeForm: NgForm) {
    if (subscribeForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.subscribeService.subscribeToList(this.subscribeData).subscribe({
      complete: () => {this.subscribeData}, 
      next: () => {this.onSuccess}, 
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

However, in the console log `console.log('err', err)`, though the submit form returns a `200` response from the sever, I did notice a JSONP error:

```
Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.
message:  "Http failure response for https://xxxxxxx.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=afd1f3490xxxxxxxx7883fb&amp;id=035xxxx952&amp;f_id=009fa6e0f0&EMAIL=xxxxxx@icloud.com&c_afd1f34907923e052b17883fb_009fa6e0f0=&c=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "JSONP Error"
url: "https://xxxxxx.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=afd1f349xxxxxxx7883fb&amp;id=035b97f952&amp;f_id=009xxxxf0&EMAIL=xxxxx@icloud.com&c_afd1f34907923e052b17883fb_009fa6e0f0=&c=ng_jsonp_call
```

If my `onSuccess` navigation route function/syntax is correct, I'm assuming that the reason it is not redirecting is because of this error in the console.

**subscribe.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubscribeService {
  mailChimpEndpoint = 'https://xxxxxx.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=afd1f3490xxxxxxxxxb&amp;id=035b9xxxx52&amp;f_id=009faxxxf0';
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  subscribeToList(data: any) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('EMAIL', data.email)
      .set('afd1f3490xxxxxxxxxxb_009fa6e0f0', '');
    const mailChimpUrl = `${this.mailChimpEndpoint}&${params.toString()}`;
    return this.http.jsonp(mailChimpUrl, 'c')
  }
}
```

How do I fix this JSON P error and correctly redirect after submission?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JSONP will cause the error that you are seeing when using the Angular HttpClient.

There is a HttpClientJsonpModule that can be used instead of the HttpClientModule, and it does support JSONP.

Documentation is at https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule